how to return a list of employee's names with the highest pay rate in java
Assume i have a valid Employee class. I create a PayRoll class with main method.
`
public class PayRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create 6 Employee objects Employee(String name, String id, int hours, double rate)
        Employee e1 = new Employee("Melissa Black", "M7620", 30, 50.00);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Richard Hamerly", "R2304", 45, 35.00);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Bruce Beverly", "B9201", 25, 30.00);
        Employee e4 = new Employee("Jessica Khan", "K7248", 42, 60.00);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("Tom Sylvester", "S3810", 40, 45.00);
        Employee e6 = new Employee("Ariana Bailey", "B4092", 40, 60.00);

        //create an Employee array and add the objects above
        Employee[] list = {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6};
        System.out.print(highRateEmployee(list));

         }
 //method that returns the name of the employee with the highest payrate
    public static String highRateEmployee(Employee [] list) {
        double max = list[0].getPayRate();
        String name = list[0].getName();
        for(int i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].getPayRate() > max) {
                max = list[i].getPayRate();
                name = list[i].getName();
            }
        }
        return name;
}

I create a function that return only the first employee with the highest payrate. Output of the following function is Jessica Khan.
//method that returns the name of the employee with the highest payrate
    public static String highRateEmployee(Employee [] list) {
        double max = list[0].getPayRate();
        String name = list[0].getName();
        for(int i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].getPayRate() > max) {
                max = list[i].getPayRate();
                name = list[i].getName();
            }

        }
        return name;
    }

How can I make a function that return a list of employee's names with the highest pay? Here's my attempt. I tried creating an arraylist name instead of name and use .add() method. However, it appears error that "Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type String[]" when I'm trying to write "name.add(list[i].getName());"
    public static String[] highRateEmployee(Employee [] list) {
        double max = list[0].getPayRate();
        String[] name = {};
        for(int i=1; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].getPayRate() >= max) {
                max = list[i].getPayRate();
                name.add(list[i].getName());
            }

        }
        return name;
    }


You can't add elements to an array. Sounds like you're looking for an ArrayList.

As people have said, you should use a List, but it doesn't necessarily have to be an ArrayList — unless you are required to return a String[]. I would make the method public static List<Employee> highRateEmployee ... returning a List instead of an Array, and returning Employee objects rather than Strings of names.

Off topic: Employee[] list = { new Employee("Melissa Black", "M7620", 30, 50.00), new Employee("Richard Hamerly", "R2304", 45, 35.00), new Employee("Bruce Beverly", "B9201", 25, 30.00), new Employee("Jessica Khan", "K7248", 42, 60.00), new Employee("Tom Sylvester", "S3810", 40, 45.00),  new Employee("Ariana Bailey", "B4092", 40, 60.00) };

As suggested, you should use an ArrayList so you can add the names when you find them.  However, your method as written even using lists won't work.
That is because you are adjusting max as you iterate across the employee list. So if the first value of max is 35 and you find one greater, you will add it to the list.  Doing it this way you will be adding names who have rates less than the max. In fact, you are omitting the first employee entirely from the test regardless.
To solve this I recommend using a Map<Double, List<String>> See HashMap

iterate over the employee list.
use Map#computeIfAbsent to put the payrate and associated name.  First time the rate is encoutered, a list is added, then the name added to the list.  If the rate is already there, the name is added for that rate.
continue updating max for final retrieval of the list of names.

public static List<String> highRateEmployee(List<Employee> employees) {

        Map<Double, List<String>> names = new HashMap<>();
        double max = 0;
        for (Employee emp : employees) {
            names.computeIfAbsent(emp.getPayRate(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                    .add(emp.getName);
            max = Math.max(max, emp.getPayRate());
        }
        return names.get(max);
}

The returned list of names would be
[Jessica Khan, Ariana Bailey]

Update
If you want to view the map after it has been populated, you can do the following:
names.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

prints
35.0=[Richard Hamerly]
45.0=[Tom Sylvester]
50.0=[Melissa Black]
60.0=[Jessica Khan, Ariana Bailey]
30.0=[Bruce Beverly]


ArrayList
String[] name = {};

This creates an array, not an ArrayList. An ArrayList is a class that implements List & SequencedCollection. ArrayList allows for dynamic addition.
What you'll need to do is declare that as:
List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

Once you do that, you should have access to the add() method. At a glance it looks like your code will then start doing what you expect of it.

Try this, with Stream API
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Solution {
    public static List<String> highRateEmployee(Employee[] employees) {
        Map<Double, List<String>> data = Arrays.stream(employees).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSalary, Collectors.mapping(Employee::getName, Collectors.toList())));
        return data.get(Collections.max(data.keySet()));
    }
}


try this:
public List<String> highRateEmployees(Employee[] employees) {
    return Arrays.stream(employees)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSalary))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}


Convert the employee array to a stream
Group by salary
Find the highest salary
Extract the list of names of employees with the highest salary
Handle null values


Sort, grab last one, filter for similar
Other Answers have clever solutions, but are a bit complicated and fancy. Here is more basic solution based on the fact that we can sort a List by examining one of the member fields.
Our data
Define a record to represent our PayCard. I changed the name as your choice of Employee is misleading.
record PayCard( String name , String id , int hours , double rate ) { }

Some sample data. We create an unmodifiable List of PayCard objects, for its convenient literals syntax. Then we feed that list to the constructor of a modifiable List such as ArrayList.
final List < PayCard > payCards = new ArrayList <> (
        List.of (
                new PayCard ( "Melissa Black" , "M7620" , 30 , 50.00 ) ,
                new PayCard ( "Richard Hamerly" , "R2304" , 45 , 35.00 ) ,
                new PayCard ( "Bruce Beverly" , "B9201" , 25 , 30.00 ) ,
                new PayCard ( "Jessica Khan" , "K7248" , 42 , 60.00 ) ,
                new PayCard ( "Tom Sylvester" , "S3810" , 40 , 45.00 ) ,
                new PayCard ( "Ariana Bailey" , "B4092" , 40 , 60.00 )
        )
);

Sorting
Next we sort using the List#sort, a recent alternative to the older Collections.sort method. In either case, we pass a Comparator to specify the member field on which we want to sort. As a shortcut to defining our Comparator, we use the static method Comparator.comparing Double. We specify the desired member field by way of the method reference PayCard :: rate, which means for each of the PayCard objects being compared, call the rate() method to extract a double value, and compare those extracted double values.
payCards.sort ( Comparator.comparingDouble ( PayCard :: rate ) );

Now that we know our List is sorted by rate of pay, we know the highest pay rate is at the bottom. So grab the last element from the list. Extract the double rate-of-pay.
final double highestRate = payCards.getLast ( ).rate ( );

Sorting for matching pay rate
Next we need to go through all the PayCard elements to see if any others coincidentally have the very same double value as a rate of pay.
If we had enormous amounts of data, we may want to optimize this search by starting at the bottom, and working backwards through the list. We keep going backwards until we get one that is less than the highest — we know for certain we need not go any further after that, given that the elements have been sorted.
But for smaller amounts of data we need not optimize. We can more easily write code to use Java streams to filter out those elements where the rate-of-pay is not a match for our highest rate.
In modern Java, the List interface is a sub-interface of SequencedCollection. Generally best to use the highest level of inheritance that meets our needs. So here we refer to our newly produced List object as a SequencedCollection.
final SequencedCollection < PayCard > highestRatePaycards =
        payCards
                .stream ( )
                .filter ( payCard -> payCard.rate ( ) == highestRate )
                .toList ( );

If your are not comfortable with streams, the above code could be done using a loop to fill another new ArrayList.
Lastly, print out text for each of our narrowed list (or SequencedCollection).
highestRatePaycards.forEach ( System.out :: println );

We see two pay cards that share the highest rate of pay of 60.00.

PayCard[name=Jessica Khan, id=K7248, hours=42, rate=60.0]
PayCard[name=Ariana Bailey, id=B4092, hours=40, rate=60.0]

